# Overflow and Underflow in C

Tags: c

What can a person do to find out how their system responds to an overflow condition? Describe a way a person can test how their system responds to an underflow condition.

I do understand what an overflow and an underflow is, I looked this up on wikipedia, but I do not understand how it can be tested from system to system.

Comment: Get an number, increment it until it overflows, see what you end up with.

Comment: Is this question about arithmetic overflows and whether a software system treats them gracefully or just ignores them? If it is about testing existing software (such as a calculator) you could manually trigger an overflow by entering numbers that are too big to handle by the application. A possible and appropriate response would be an error message (such as `overflow error`). An inappropriate response would be a calculation result that is wrong due to the overflow.

Comment: Nobu Games, but how would that vary for an overflow and underflow?

Comment: As far as I know the arithmetic underflow problem would be a number that is too small to be representable as a floating point number in memory. You could multiply two very small numbers, where the product would be smaller than the minimum and see the result.

Comment: How would I know what the minimum is?

Comment: @HotLicks: Try that with a floating-point number. As soon as it reaches a value such that `N + 1.0 == N`, you'll have an infinite loop.

Comment: @KeithThompson - Then you have your answer.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yes, you have your answer as soon as the infinite loop finishes. I'm a patient man, but ...

Comment: @KeithThompson - Seriously, if it's IEEE floating point then "overflow" is very well defined by the standard and need not be separately tested for each platform.

Comment: You can look up both specifications for single and double-precision floating point numbers. Wikipedia says that "the smallest non-zero positive number that can be represented is 1×10^−101": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Range_of_floating-point_numbers

Answer (score 2):

With `unsigned` integers, C requires underflow and overflow to behave in a certain manner.  For example, consider the following:

```
unsigned int uintUnderflow = 0;
unsigned int uintOverflow = UINT_MAX;

printf("%u\n", --uintUnderflow); // Guaranteed to be UINT_MAX
printf("%u\n", ++uintOverflow);  // Guaranteed to be 0
```

Now with `signed` integers, implementations may define underflow and overflow however they wish.  That is the nature of undefined behavior.  If you can't find documentation on how it will behave you'll have to experiment with it yourself:

```
int intUnderflow = INT_MIN;
int intOverflow = INT_MAX;

printf("%d\n", --intUnderflow); // Implementation defined
printf("%d\n", ++intOverflow);  // Implementation defined
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming you mean c. Something like

```
 int main()
 {

    int i = 0;

    while(1)
   {
     i++;
    }

 }
```

light fuse and stand well back

Comment: Im not understanding the distinction in how this would test for an overflow or an underflow.

Comment: This produces no output. The typical response to signed integer overflow is silent wraparound. Strictly speaking, this program has undefined behavior, but in practice it's probably just an infinite loop.

Comment: so now you know the systems response to overflow - silently ignored. THat was the purpose of the exercise

Answer (score 1):

For integer numbers, encoded in 2-complement, there's a way to detect overflow after an addition operation: check the signs of both operands and result. If operands have the same sign but result hasn't, there was an overflow.

```
int is_overflow (char a, char b, char res)
{
  char mask = (1<<(8*sizeof(char)-1));
  if ((a & mask) == (b & mask) && (a & mask) != (res & mask))
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}
```

For example:

```
char a = 127;
char b = 1;
char c = a + b; 
is_overflow (a, b, c) => 1

char a = -128;
char b = -1;
char c = a + b; 
is_overflow (a, b, c) => 1

char a = -1;
char b = 1;
char c = a + b; 
is_overflow (a, b, c) => 0

char a = 1;
char b = 1;
char c = a + b; 
is_overflow (a, b, c) => 0
```

For underflow, the thing is different. I don't know about integer underflow, but floating point underflow. For these situations, the numeric processor has flags to test whether the last operation underflowed, but I don't know of a portable way to test those flags from C.

Comment: 2's-complement encoding doesn't necessarily imply anything about the behavior on overflow. *Typically* computing `INT_MAX + 1` will wrap around and give you `INT_MIN`, but the behavior is not defined by the C standard; it could crash or do literally anything.

Comment: I believe 2-complement enconding has a well defined behaviour on overflow, and that is the way addition works at CPU level. In fact, the overflow bit that is commonly stored in a flag register is calculated the way I've shown (or an equivalent way). Why an addition that overflows should crash the process (by itself, not by any side effect resulting from the overflow)?

Comment: In most implementations, yes. But 2's-complement defines a storage format; it doesn't by itself define the behavior on overflow. The ISO C language standard permits 2's-complement, 1's-complement, and sign-and-magnitude representations for signed integer types, but explicitly states that the behavior on arithmetic overflow is undefined. This can actually have a visible effect because an optimizing compiler may *assume* that a program's behavior is not undefined; for example, it might reduce `INT_MAX + 1 > INT_MAX` to true (`1`) without actually performing the calculation.

Comment: Did you actually test your code? Since `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1 your mask ends up as 1 all the time and your code doesn't check anything for overflow but rather that the arguments to the function are some strange combination of odd and even.

Comment: Opps! Forgot a *8 here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
    int n = INT_MAX;
    ++n;
    printf("INT_MAX + 1: %d\n", n);

    unsigned u = UINT_MAX;
    ++u;
    printf("UINT_MAX + 1: %u\n", u);

    n = INT_MIN;
    --n;
    printf("INT_MIN - 1: %d\n", n);

    u = 0;
    --u;
    printf("0u - 1: %u\n", u);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The behavior for unsigned integer types is mandated by the C standard; for example. `UINT_MAX + 1 == 0` for any conforming C implementation.