# Arithmetic overflow in C++17

Tags: c++, x86, g++, clang, language-lawyer

1. Is arithmetic overflow well defined per C++17 for `uint8_t`, `uint16_t` ,`uint32_t`, `uint64_t`?  If yes, what are the defined behavior (excerpt from C++ standard is highly appreciated)
2. Is arithmetic overflow well defined per C++17 for `int8_t`, `int16_t` ,`int32_t`, `int64_t`?  (excerpt from C++ standard is highly appreciated)
3. If any or all of above is implementation specific, what are the definitions for g++ and clang?
4. If it is architecture specific (as Havenard pointed out), my question is specific to x86(-64).
5. What if I do smaller unsigned int - bigger unsigned int, is it well-defined?

I saw the first answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272304/overflow-and-underflow-in-c) mentions that to my question #1, it is defined in C standard although he didn't quote it and I can't find anything about in C++ standard.

=================

Update 1:

removed "underflow" per ach as it is the wrong term (thanks @ach).  Added #5 to express what I really meant by "underflow" (incorrectly)

Comment: Nothing has changed `unsgined` integer over/underflow is well defined, `signed` is not.

Comment: It's architecture specific, it's not determined by the language.

Comment: @Havenard updated.  thanks!

Comment: @George do you have a reference doc somewhere to share?  I would like to see what the defined behaviors are so that I can take advantage of it.  Thanks!

Comment: [Arithmetic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) has a small section on overflows.

Comment: @HCSF "_do you have a reference doc somewhere to share?_" [C++ standard](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard).

Comment: Even though [`int32_t` and the other signed fixed-width types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) are guaranteed to be 2's complement if an implementation provides it at all, it's still undefined behaviour to overflow it because it's signed.  Actual behaviour of a program with undefined behaviour may be arch-specific and compiler-specific, but the C++ standard has nothing to say about it.  (And the behaviour doesn't have to make any sense without looking at the asm.  http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

Comment: A note on terminology: there is no integer-arithmetic underflow. Underflow only applies to floating-point arithmetics. It happens when a result of computation is smaller by absolute value than representable.

Comment: @ach so if I do `uint8_t(0) - uint8_t(1)`, what is it called?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius  Thanks.  I did read the first section SergeyA quoted below but I don't get it and I was hoping that I missed few more sections about overflow/underflow.

Comment: @HCSF Generally, that's overflow. But in case of C/C++, that's regular arithmetics; it's well-defined; I myself call this wraparound, but I'm totally unsure if this word is suitable.

Comment: @ach If it is called overflow as well, then the behavior of `uint8_t(0) - uint8_t(1)` should be covered by section 6.7.1 (SergeyA pasted the excerpt in his answer).  Tho, section 6.7.1 mentions "largest value" but no the "smallest value".  So I am confused what standard says about this specific kind of "overflow".

Comment: @ach if it is a well-defined regular arithmetic.  I wonder which section in C++ standard talks about it so that I can leverage it.

Comment: @HCSF You're missing my point: from point of view of general computer science, that's overflow - arithmetic operation produces a value which is not representable in the target type. But C and C++ specifically define that operations on unsigned integers are in modulo arithmetics, so overflow is not possible.

Comment: Sorry just clarified 14 seconds before you posted...

Answer (score 6):

In hopes of creating a canonical, here are some normative specs (quotes taken from the latest C++ draft):

- Unsigned integers do not overflow: see 6.7.1:

> Unsigned integers shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2n where n
>   is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular
>   size of integer. (44) This implies that unsigned arithmetic does not
>   overflow because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting
>   unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater
>   than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting
>   unsigned integer type.

- Signed integer overflow/underflow is undefined: see 7.1.4:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not
>   mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for
>   its type, the behavior is undefined.

By the way, none of it is implementation specific, and compilers aggressively exploit over/underflows for optimization. For example, as demonstrated by the following snippet:

```
void a();
void b();

void foo(int k) {
    int z = k+1;
    if (z < k) {
        a();
    } else {
        b();
    }
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/0re-nM - the branch is eliminated, even though on real platform due to modulo 2 representation, `z` could actually become lesser than `k`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I also read 6.7.1 previously.  But it is unclear to me what it actually means by "one greater than the largest vale".  So for `uint32_t`, max `uint32_t` + 1 is 4294967296.  How should it be represented?  What does "reduced modulo" mean?  Shifting bits to the left?  Or?

Comment: I just looked at your example.  You are using signed integer to demo, which falls into the undefined behavior section 7.1.4 points out.  No?

Comment: Basically in your example, `z` is guaranteed to be equal to `k` right at the `if` statement and since they are the same for sure (even tho `++k` is undefined), and so compiler can safely eliminate the branch I think.

Comment: Since ++k overflowing would be UB the compiler can assume it never happens. So z == k+1 all the time and it removes the branch.

Comment: Since the question is also about small types, you need to mention integer promotion somehow...

Comment: A more interesting case, IMHO, is `unsigned mul_mod_65536(uint16_t x, uint16_t y) { return (x*y) & 0xFFFF;}`.  The authors of the Standard described in the rationale how they would expect the majority of current (and presumably future) implementations to process that, but didn't actually mandate such behavior (they probably thought compilers would behave that way whether or not they were ordered to).  Consequently, gcc will not consistently handle the function as described in the Rationale.